# Prevent ContextMenuStrip from firing over child Controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Control with a context menu. The Control has a child Control. I want the context menu to appear only when the user clicks on an area of the Control *not* covered by its child Control.

Of course I can actually check for each child Control using screen coordinates. My question is: Is there any simple or built-in way to have only the right-clicks immediately over the Control show the context menu?